# Is there an existing key map to select a specific tab in jupyter lab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

This is a jupyter lab screen shot.

There are 2 tabs each of which is being pointed by a red arrow.

[image]

command + numbers could select a specific tab on chrome on mac, is there an existing key map to select a specific tab like that?

I am not talking about switch previous/next by using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>.

I am talking about something like that command + 3 would directly select 3rd tab